# oracle sample clause performance impact with database upgrade

Tags: performance, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, random

I have some SQLs running on ORACLE 10g database. Some of these SQLs were using oracle sample clause.
e.g.

```
select /*+ use_nl(emp,dept) +*/ *
from emp, dept
sample(10)
where emp.deptno=dept.deptno
```

Now, the oracle 10g will be upgraded to 11g. We have to proove that there is no performance impact for the sample clause for the database upgrade. In other words, I should proove the sample clause working well in oracle 11g on performance aspect.

But I spent a whole day on search on google, no expected answer. 
Could you give me a answer or suggestion on it? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

Well the good news is that it's exactly the same clause used internally by Oracle for sampling -- most notably for DBMS_Stats programs. So I'd say that it's rather unlikely that it's done anything other than get faster.

The bad news is that there are an enormous number of issues that might harm or improve performance during an upgrade, but where there is a problem you are most likely going to find out pretty quickly and there will be a fix available. However, someone doesn't want to be held to blame if *anything at all* changes during the upgrade, and is covering their arse by making you waste your time on efforts that are bound to be unproductive and inconclusive.

The correct way to investigate this is to set up a new system with the new version that you are actually going to be using -- no cut-down data sets, no export-import if what you're going to do is an in-place upgrade (you want the physical data layout to be exactly the same as production), no "small representative set of queries", using the same storage architecture, processor type and memory configuration. Run your actual application on real data and compare performance before and after upgrade in a meaningful way.

It is absolutely the only way to be sure, because the fundamental problem with the task that you've been set is that you have to look for evidence of something (a performance problem) not existing. It's like trying to prove the non-existence of invisible pixies in your washing machine that eat one sock out of every pair -- practically impossible! The burden of proof lies with those who say that something might exist.

http://www.logicallyfallacious.com/index.php/logical-fallacies/146-proving-non-existence

Here are some constructive steps you can take:

1. Search Metalink -- this is the number one authoratative source for upgrade problems, because problems get reported via Metalink and either a bug is raised, or an explanation is published.
2. Search the Oracle forums -- if there is a general change in behaviour that people are encountering then they'll question it here.
3. Search the internet generally.

If you've done all of those then that's the limit of the efforts you can be expected to take.

If that's not enough then you or the people behind this migration just have to escalate it, and ask some awkward questions: Was this level of proof required in moving from 9i to 10g? Is it required for upgrades from 10.2.0.2 to 10.2.0.5?

I'd really love to know the politics behind this -- it sounds like a dreadful place to work.

Comment: I would also suggest that you consider removing hints when upgrading. The CBO has changed in 11 and will make better/different decisions you may find your well thought out hint from 10 actually makes your query slower in 11. This would be a better use of time than testing sample.

Comment: Yes that hint doesn't make sense to me in the presence of the sample clause -- hopefully it's not a real query.

Comment: David, Thank you for your reply, I still need to give a proof， even an authoritative article on the internet talking about this topic. but i did not find.

Comment: More added above -- the problem is that if there is no issue, then there will be no article authoritative or otherwise. "Upgraded from 10.2 to 11.2 -- here's two pages of analysis on why there is no performance problem with one particular SQL clause"